# How much of an object (containing std::vectors) is loaded in to the L1/L2/L3 cache?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, cpu, data-oriented-design

Please see the following link, page 22 onwards:

http://research.scee.net/files/presentations/gcapaustralia09/Pitfalls_of_Object_Oriented_Programming_GCAP_09.pdf

the above link suggests if I have an object containing vectors/arrays like this:

```
class MyClass{
    public:
    double a[1000];
    double b[1000];
};
```

and the code below iterates through a vector of MyClass and performs some Math on std::vector b:

```
std::vector<MyClass> y;
y.populateVector();

for(auto x : y){
    //Iterate though x.b and do some math;
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
        std::cout << x.b[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

when we retrieve each MyClass object all the data from both of the arrays will be loaded in to the cache line. Is this true? I didnt think the data `a` would be loaded in to the cache line because the address for accessing `b` would be calculated and loaded.

**I am trying to get an idea how much of a MyClass object is loaded in to the cache in comparison to the useful data required for processing?**

I can understand if the very first `b` element shared the same cache line as the very last  `a` elementbut I didnt think the whole object would get loaded in to the L2/L3 cache just to process one part of the object?

Comment: In your case, the double arrays are not stored inside the class directly, but in other memory locations. The std::vector stores just a pointer. So there is little chance that accessing b data loads a data in the cache

Comment: In the document you mention, data is stored directly inside the structure. You could do it by using double a[16]; instead of std::vector<double> a; in this case a and b will be contiguous in memory and have a reasonable chance to be in the same cache line.

Comment: I'm going to change my example code to reflect this.

Comment: Your code doesn't retrieve the `MyClass` objects, as far as I can tell. You just iterate through references to them and access their `b` member. What about your code do you think constitutes "retrieve"?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz isn't the concept of an object quite a loose term? I have just included some more code above, to access the b array I would say the object MyClass is being accessed?

Comment: Yes, but what does it mean to "retrieve" an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the way that the memory is organized on your system. If it just so happens that the backing arrays for `a` and `b` are located very closely in memory (since the CPU will usually issue larger reads to fill cache in the hopes you use it) it's possible that they will be loaded. If not I see no reason for reading `b` would imply anything to do with `a` aside from attempting to read some pointers from where the class actually resides in memory.

What it does show is that using classes in haphazard manners can and will cause cache misses just because of the way that they reside in memory.

General rule for what gets loaded into the cache is, if the CPU issues a read and misses the cache it will load a cache aligned chunk from main memory (in the examples there 128 bytes).

For your edited example, Yes these are colocated pieces of memory and parts of `a` MAY be loaded if reads to `b` are issued just because of their location in memory.

For your example, each `MyClass` object consists of a contiguous region of `2000 * sizeof(double)` bytes (most likely aligned). These objects are packed into a continuous memory region pointed to by the vector. Accessing the `b` member of each object will incur a cache miss (if it's not cached). The contents of a cache aligned piece of memory will be loaded from the each read that misses the cache. Depending on the memory alignment constraints and cache size it's possible that some of the entries from the `a` member will be loaded into memory. It's even possible to assume that due to padding and alignment that it will not be the case that any of your `MyClass` `a` members will be loaded into the cache (and there's no reason they should be as they were not accessed).

Comment: Did you see the link though? Their presentation slides implies the whole object is loaded, i.e. vectors a and b are loaded?

Comment: Just to let you know I changed the example code from vector to static array.

Comment: @user997112 I think you're confusing the object itself (consisting of some pointers) versus the contents of the vectors (which is being pointed to by those pointers). If by the whole object you mean the 2 pointers then yes those will be loaded into memory most likely.

Comment: @user997112 Updated my answer for static arrays. But unlikely that all of `a` will be read as it exceeds the size of a cache line.

Comment: So this is how I presumed it would work- address of b would be calculated. If b begins halfway through a cache line then some of a may be in the first cache line- but thats it. However, their example seems to load the wholeeeeeeee object.

Comment: I don't really get that from their examples, just giving it a quick read it shows the object in memory and the object being loaded into cache piece by piece.

Comment: What about in slide 38? Are we saying my example is slightly difference because they are using all of the data in the object whereas in my simple example I am not?

Comment: @user997112 In slide 38 they dereference an iterator to a statically allocated array (the backing array of a `std::vector`). Since the entire array is less than the size of a cache line the whole thing is loaded.

Comment: @user997112 In your example the object exceeds the size of a cache line and all the memory for that object is contiguous. In their case the vector is pointing to another region of memory altogether and their vector contents are smaller than a cache line.

Comment: But if you look at the diagram of the cache in slide 38, to me that looks like they have put the whole object in to the L2 cache?

Comment: @user997112 The whole object is loaded because they attempt to access a member of it so most of it gets pulled into one cache line. They then access something else in the object which causes the remainder to be preemptively loaded into cache. It's simply because of the access pattern and that they are allocating their matrices statically within those objects.

Comment: Ok so if I understand you correctly the most inefficient access pattern would be to have a vector<char> and then iterate through a vector<MyClass> and printing out the first element from the vector<char>. From the whole cache line only 1 byte would contain "useful" data?

Comment: That would be one example of inefficiency.

Answer (score 3):

Your declaration:

```
for(auto x : y) ...
```

declares `x` as a value instead of a reference.  It's possible that the compiler could optimize away copying each element of `y` into the local variable `x`, but I wouldn't count on it.

If you write:

```
for(auto &x : y) ...
```

Then the loop will work on references to the objects in `y`.  I'm assuming that's what you meant to do.

In concrete terms, ignoring struct padding: the compiler will convert

```
double temp = y[i].b[j];
```

into something equivalent to

```
double temp = *(
    y.data() + i * sizeof(MyClass) // start of y[i]
    + 1000 * sizeof(double)        // skip over y[i].a
    + j * sizeof(double));         // get to the right place in y[i].b
```

and it will load the cache-line-sized block containing that address into a cache line.

Then, as you iterate over more elements of `y[i].b`, many of them will already be in the cache.

Since the arrays contain 1000 elements each, they are much bigger than cache lines on a typical CPU.  1000 doubles take up 8000 bytes, whereas cache lines on the Sandy Bridge architecture (for example) are 64 bytes.  Iterating over the arrays will saturate the cache effectively.  You might waste part of a cache line on the first and final elements of `x.a`, but the effect should be small.  **As the size of your arrays increases, the significance of these wasted loads approaches 0.**

The Playstation article talks about objects that are comparable in size to a cache line.  Those optimizations won't matter as much for big objects like yours.

Answer (score 1):

In the link you are referring to, the two arrays `a` and `b` are 4x4 matrices, which means 16 elements each. As this is about a video game, they are likely floating-point. 16 floats take 64 bytes.
A CPU cache line is 128 bytes. So there is a significant chance that a large part of `a` is in the same cache line than `b[0]`. Statistically, 50% of `a` will be in the same cache line than `b[0]`. Reading `b[0]` will then load that part of `a` in the cache.
If you manage to align the class/struct on 128 bytes, you will be even guaranteed that `a` and `b` fit entirely in the same cache line.

Now in your example you do not use 16 floats but 1000 doubles. That is 8000 bytes, much larger than a typical cache line. A few last elements of `a` may be in the same cache line than `b[0]` but the effect will be small.